# SignalR scaleout with Redis Cluster

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr-backplane

I read the Microsoft documentation of SignalR and says that:

> SignalR scaleout with Redis does not support Redis clusters.

but the documentation is 06/10/2014.
To date there is a solution to use the Redis backplane with a cluster redis?
Or how could I solve the problem? some idea?
thank you

Comment: Is there any reason in your infrastructure that you couldn't have a completely separate redis instance running just for the backplane?

Comment: Yes, because i save the session token and clientId in redis

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3765 "This may mean that they may need to use a different Redis database for SignalR if they are currently sharing their Redis database with applications that require clustering."

Comment: Sorry but if the redis server goes down as the application does to work again?!

Comment: Can I put a reverse proxy (HAProxy) in front of the redis cluster to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a solution than this is what you need:

For .net framework:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.StackExchangeRedis

For .net core:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.StackExchangeRedis